# The use of unitary operators in translating between reference frames in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, symmetry, observables, unitarity

In Chapter 2.6 of his *Lectures on groups and vector spaces for physicists*, Isham describes how different observers (different reference frames) must describe the same quantum system.

Consider two observers, Fred and Fred', who are at different points in space. Isham says "a given physical state of the system will be described by them using different state vector (but in the same Hilbert space) since the system looks different in certain ways when viewed from their particular perspectives" which I can accept as, essentially, a consequence of each wanting to use the same Hilbert space despite being in different places. Fred and Fred' assign the state of the system to different vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}'$ in $\mathcal{H}$.

From the appropriate relativity principle, no phenomenon should depend on reference frame. That is, **if** "both observers measure the same physical observable $O$ [NB, a physical observable is a physical quantity, not an operator] in which the eigenstates corresponding to a particular eigenvalue $\mu$ are assigned by them to be the eigenvectors $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{e}'$ of the operators $\hat{O}$ and $\hat{O}'$ which they respectively use, then we should have $|\langle \mathbf{e},\mathbf{v}\rangle| = |\langle \mathbf{e}',\mathbf{v}'\rangle|$ in order that both observers predict the same probabilities of getting the various common results for the value of the observable $O$."

It is this which I am struggling to parse. I am trying to understand why it is a requirement that  I believe the crux of my question is **what precisely is the observable $O$ meant to be here?** Consider the "position of the system" as the observable. By this do we mean "the position of the system relative to the given observer" (so that there are different values for different observers) or "the position of the system relative to some fixed point" (in which case the requirements set out by Isham make sense)?

If the latter, we are then led via Wigner's theorem to the conclusion that unitary operators can be used to "translate" between different observers who are using the same Hilbert space. However, this seems a very restricted use of **observable** and I am therefore not sure if I am misunderstanding.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147689/discussion-on-question-by-ee18-the-use-of-unitary-operators-in-translating-betwe); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Fred studies a physical system. According to Fred, the system is in state $|v\rangle$. Fred measures some property $O$ of the system. For definiteness, think of $O$ as position of the system. Fred sets up the eigenvalue equation $\hat{O}|e\rangle=\mu|e\rangle$. The possible results of the measurement are the eigenvalues $\mu$. The amplitude for the measurement result to be $\mu$ is $\langle e|v\rangle$.

Now consider how Fred' interprets the activities of Fred. The lab of Fred is actively transformed wrt the lab of Fred' by a unitary operator $\hat{U}$. (Incidentally, I think that unitary operators correspond to canonical transformations not just inertial transformations.) So, according to Fred', the state of the system under study by both observers is $|v'\rangle=\hat{U}|v\rangle$. Fred' says that Fred is using the operator $\hat{U}\hat{O}\hat{U}^{-1}$. In other words, in the lab of Fred', the operator being used by Fred appears to be $\hat{U}\hat{O}\hat{U}^{-1}$. Fred' wants to know the possible results a measurement can have in the experiment performed by Fred so Fred' studies the eigenvalues of $\hat{U}\hat{O}\hat{U}^{-1}$. This is,
\begin{equation}
(\hat{U}\hat{O}\hat{U}^{-1})(\hat{U}|e\rangle)=\mu(\hat{U}|e\rangle)
\end{equation}
The eigenvalue spectrum is the same as the spectrum found by Fred. The eigenvectors worked out by Fred' are $U|e\rangle$. This makes sense because any state $|\rangle$ reported by Fred appears to Fred' as $\hat{U}|\rangle$. The amplitude for the measurement performed by Fred, as it appears to Fred' is $\langle e|\hat{U}^{-1}\hat{U}|v\rangle$. Happily, this the same amplitude as obtained by Fred. So, Fred' and Fred completely agree on what happened when Fred measured the system.

Now suppose that Fred' does his own measurement of the system. He uses the operator $\hat{O}$. The possible results of the measurement are the eigenvalues of $\hat{O}|e\rangle=\mu|e\rangle$. Fred' performs the measurement. The amplitude for getting the result $\mu$ is $\langle e|\hat{U}|v\rangle$ because the state of the system is $\hat{U}|v\rangle$ according to Fred'. So, Fred' does not agree with Fred on the amplitude for measuring value $\mu$. This also meakes sense because the system is in a different place wrt the lab of Fred' than it is wrt the lab of Fred.

Comment: To confirm, when you say "For definiteness, think of $O$ as position of the system", does that mean "position of the system relative to Fred's frame"? That is, do *both* Fred and Fred' call $O$ "position of the system relative to Fred's frame"?

Comment: @EE18 : $O$ is the position of the system relative to the user's lab. So, if Fred uses $O$ to measure the position of the system relative to his lab. Similarly, Fred' uses $O$ to measure the position of the system relative to his lab.

Comment: I am confused then. If $O$ for Fred is "distance from Fred" and $O$ for Fred' is "distance from Fred' " then, in a given state for the system, we would expect them to get different results (and the same eigenvalue construction therefore makes little sense)?

Comment: See also my edit if that helps clarify my issue. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @EE18 : Your comment in the discussion under your question is correct according to my understanding. You wrote, " when we say "position" we should really say "position with respect to Fred". Then $\hat{O}$ is the operator representing the "position with respect to Fred" observable in Fred's frame, and $\hat{O}′$ is the operator representing the "position with respect to Fred" observable in the Fred' frame. "